# Google Drive API performance (large number of files, large number of sharing)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-workspace

I created an account with the Business option of G-suite and added 5 users to use unlimited Google storage. 
After I create a folder on that storage and upload the file, I will share it with other users with the View Only option.

Please Look at this directory structure.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2wk7Q.png)

In this case, I'm worrying about performance issue.

I need to prepare for the case where the number of users increases and our system slows down.

Do you know how much IOPS(input/output operations per second) does Google Drive provide?
And, Do you know What is different team drive and my drive and what is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regard to your Team Drive and Google Drive comparison inquiry, refer to this

[What can you do with Team Drives?](https://gsuite.google.com/learning-center/products/drive/get-started-team-drive/):

> Google Team Drives are shared spaces where teams can easily store,
>   search, and access their files anywhere, from any device. Unlike files
>   in My Drive, files in Team Drive belong to the team instead of an
>   individual. Even if members leave, the files stay exactly where they
>   are so your team can continue to share information and get work done.
>   Note: Team Drives is available on G Suite Enterprise, G Suite
>   Business, or G Suite for Education editions. If you can’t use Team
>   Drives, contact your G Suite administrator.

Not sure if Google's IO operations/second is openly disclosed but if you think you're about to run into scaling problem, by looking at your Google Drive API dashboard, you can always reach out to Drive team to [request for more quota](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/limits-quotas#additional_quota).